# Java Swing: Forcing certain items to the end of a sorted JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How do I force certain table rows to be at the end of a sorted JTable?  For example, if someone clicks on a column heading to sort by that column, I have some rows that I always want to be at the end of the table regardless of the sort order.  How would I go about making this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you have your JTable set up? Is there a custom TableModel operating behind the scenes, or do you use a DefaultTable Model?

Comment: Well, to create a JTable you need to pass an array of Objects to the constructor, right? If you implement a sorting method so that leaves the final rows unsorted, and then you fire it, you can probably achieve the functionality that you want.

Comment: It could be solved pretty easily with a RowSorter and a custom comparator. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for some more information. Without some code we can't provide a specific answer.

Comment: @jjiceman decided to move the comment into not-an-answer - more comfortable to write and edit :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can either implement the [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface, as shown in [*How to Use Tables: Sorting and Filtering*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), or implement the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) Interface, as shown in the  class [`Value`](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table#Value) of this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table). In either approach, you can alter the result of the comparison method in a way that causes the desired row(s) to appear after all others.

Addendum: As @kleopatra's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8501528/230513) notes, the `Comparator` must be applied in the context of the table's `RowSorter`, while an implementation of `Comparable` would affect the [*natural ordering*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html). As the result is convoluted and hard to maintain, you may want to look at an alternate approach.

Comment: decided to move the comment into not-an-answer - more comfortable to write and edit :-)

Answer (score 1):

Beware: this is not an answer, just a kind of summary of the difficulties and some links.

It's one of those tasks which are surprisingly difficult to solve. Nothing in core (not even in SwingX :-) which supports it. In particular, a Comparator doesn't help because it doesn't know anything about the sort direction that is it can't know if it should locate a particular row at the top or at the bottom. The only collaborator which might be able to do so, might be a RowSorter. Due to the fact that everything in DefaultRowSorter is tightly hidden, tweaking boils down to a complete re-implementation. An example to [handle nulls had been published by Walter Laan](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1349003) over at OTN and [later described to be tweaked](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2155623) for a more complex context.

Comment: +1 for putting this in perspective. I had no idea the implementation would be so troublesome.

Comment: @kleopatra please see bug listed (by Andrew Thompson) in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187566/problem-formatting-fields-in-a-jtable-differences-between-integer-and-double, sure there is lots for ...

Comment: @mKorbel no, that's unrelated, completely - as in no relation whatever