# Sort JTable Except for Last Row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I have a `JTable` where the last row is the total row that aggregates all other rows. When the user clicks a column header on the table, rows are sorted by that column, except for the total row which should be always at bottom.

Is there a simple way to implement this with `TableRowSorter`?

Comment: maybe @Walter Laan ([author of original code](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1349003&start=0&tstart=0)) can to commenting this issue too

Comment: Simplest solution would be to use a scroll pane that allowed footers, this way the data doesn't actually live in the table, but the scroll pane footer (like column and row footers) [jide](https://java.net/projects/jide-oss/sources/svn/content/trunk/src/com/jidesoft/swing/JideScrollPane.java?rev=1806) provides a possible solution I've used in the past that works very well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution worked for me....

In your table model update the `getRowCount()` member to return 1 row less than required.

Then modify the index and row counts reported by your sorter as follows...

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter =
    new DefaultTableRowSorter<TableModel>(this.getModel()) 
{
    public int convertRowIndexToModel(int index)
    {
        int maxRow = super.getViewRowCount();
        if (index >= maxRow)
            return index;
        return super.convertRowIndexToModel(index);
    }

    public int convertRowIndexToView(int index) 
    {
        int maxRow = super.getModelRowCount();
        if (index > maxRow)
            return index;
        return super.convertRowIndexToView(index);
    }

    public int getViewRowCount() 
    {
        return super.getViewRowCount() + 1;
    }
};

myTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this screws up any filtering added to the sorter.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would create a single-row 2nd table with the header removed, and place it directly underneath the main table, so as to create the illusion of a last row.

Besides it solving your sorting problem, it will also persist as the user scrolls that main table, which is probably a good thing since it's a "totals" row.

You could even add a `ColumnModelListener` to the main table's `TableColumnModel` to synch up column resizing.

**EDIT**: Here's the general idea:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TestFrame implements Runnable
{
  JTable mainTable;
  JTable fixedTable;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TestFrame());
  }

  public void run()
  {
    mainTable = new JTable(8, 3);
    mainTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    mainTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

    for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++)
    {
      for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
      {
        mainTable.setValueAt((int)(Math.random()*100), r, c);
      }
    }

    mainTable.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(
      new TableColumnModelListener()
      {
        public void columnAdded(TableColumnModelEvent e) {}
        public void columnRemoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {}
        public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {}
        public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {}

        public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent e)
        {
          synchColumnSizes();
        }
      });

    setVisibleRowCount(mainTable, 5);

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(mainTable);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    fixedTable = new JTable(1, 3);
    fixedTable.setValueAt("will not sort or", 0, 0);
    fixedTable.setValueAt("scroll but will",  0, 1);
    fixedTable.setValueAt("resize with main", 0, 2);

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Fixed Last Row"));
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    p.add(scroll, gbc);
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    p.add(fixedTable, gbc);

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }

  private void synchColumnSizes()
  {
    TableColumnModel tcmMain = mainTable.getColumnModel();
    TableColumnModel tcmFixed = fixedTable.getColumnModel();

    for (int i = 0; i < tcmMain.getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
      int width = tcmMain.getColumn(i).getWidth();
      tcmFixed.getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(width);
    }
  }

  public static void setVisibleRowCount(JTable table, int rows)
  {
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension( 
            table.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize().width, 
            rows * table.getRowHeight())); 
  }
}
```

Comment: agree layer by LayoutManager that hold both JTables together

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simple way to implement this with TableRowSorter?

- not isn't simple
- good idea, [quite is possible to set flag for RowSorter, its SortingKeys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6190874/714968)
- there is bug [for all ClassTypes except String instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6264846/714968)

Answer (score 1):

@Das: maybe this version is better since you do not need to override the getRowCount(), which may be used and maybe causing problems by other functions

```
public class TableRowSorterTotal<MyTableModel extends TableModel> extends TableRowSorter<TableModel>
{   

    TableRowSorterTotal(MyTableModel model)
    {
        super(model);
    }

    public int convertRowIndexToModel(int index)
    {
        int maxRow = super.getViewRowCount();
        int currModel = super.convertRowIndexToModel(index);
        int maxModel = super.convertRowIndexToModel(maxRow-1);

        if(currModel == maxModel)
            return maxRow - 1;

        if(currModel > maxModel)
            return currModel- 1;

        return currModel;
    }

    public int convertRowIndexToView(int index) 
    {
        int maxRow = super.getModelRowCount();
        int currView= super.convertRowIndexToView(index);
        int maxView = super.convertRowIndexToView(maxRow-1);

        if(currView == maxView)
            return maxRow - 1;

        if(currView > maxView)
            return currView- 1;

        return currView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37892395/230513), the complete example example below illustrates the approach in the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17092951/230513). In particular,

- The implementation of `getRowCount()` in the `TableModel` returns the `size()` of the `List<Employee>`, which is one *less* than the number of rows displayed in the table.
- The implementation of `getValueAt()` in the `TableModel` illustrates the call to `sum()` in the `COLUMN_SALARY` and some possible display choices for the remaining columns in the extra row at the bottom.
- The implementation of `getViewRowCount()` in the `TableRowSorter` enables the display of the extra row but precludes reasonable [filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37913520/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37892395/230513
 */
public class JTableColumnTotalExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(JTableColumnTotalExample::display);
    }

    public static void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("JTable Sorting Example");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        List<Employee> listEmployees = createListEmployees();
        TableModel model = new EmployeeTableModel(listEmployees);
        JTable table = new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return new Dimension(500, getRowCount() * getRowHeight());
            }
        };
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new CurrencyFormatter());
        TableRowSorter sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model) {
            @Override
            public int convertRowIndexToModel(int index) {
                int maxRow = super.getViewRowCount();
                if (index >= maxRow) {
                    return index;
                }
                return super.convertRowIndexToModel(index);
            }

            @Override
            public int convertRowIndexToView(int index) {
                int maxRow = super.getModelRowCount();
                if (index > maxRow) {
                    return index;
                }
                return super.convertRowIndexToView(index);
            }

            @Override
            public int getViewRowCount() {
                return super.getViewRowCount() + 1;
            }
        };
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static List<Employee> createListEmployees() {
        List<Employee> listEmployees = new ArrayList<>();
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Peter", "Manager", 40000));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Paul", "Programmer", 25000));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Mary", "Designer", 25000));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Donald", "Leader", 30000));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Tom", "Designer", 28000));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Samantha", "Analyst", 50000));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Jerome", "Programmer", 32000));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Jonathon", "Developer", 29000));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Kevin", "Programmer", 23000));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Anthony", "Programmer", 23000));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("John", "Designer", 33000));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("David", "Developer", 28000));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Harry", "Designer", 31000));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Charles", "Programmer", 26000));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Joseph", "Manager", 40000));
        return listEmployees;
    }

    private static class EmployeeTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private static final int COLUMN_NUM = 0;
        private static final int COLUMN_NAME = 1;
        private static final int COLUMN_JOB = 2;
        private static final int COLUMN_SALARY = 3;

        private final String[] columnNames = {"No", "Name", "Job", "Salary"};
        private final List<Employee> listEmployees;

        public EmployeeTableModel(List<Employee> listEmployees) {
            this.listEmployees = listEmployees;
            int indexCount = 1;
            for (Employee employee : listEmployees) {
                employee.setIndex(indexCount++);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return listEmployees.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
            return columnNames[columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (rowIndex == getRowCount()) {
                switch (columnIndex) {
                    case COLUMN_NUM:
                        return 999_999_999;
                    case COLUMN_NAME:
                        return "Total";
                    case COLUMN_JOB:
                        return "Salary";
                    case COLUMN_SALARY:
                        return sum();
                }
            }
            Employee employee = listEmployees.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case COLUMN_NUM:
                    return employee.getIndex();
                case COLUMN_NAME:
                    return employee.getName();
                case COLUMN_JOB:
                    return employee.getJob();
                case COLUMN_SALARY:
                    return employee.getSalary();
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid column index");
            }
        }

        private int sum() {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int r = 0; r < getRowCount(); r++) {
                sum += (int) getValueAt(r, COLUMN_SALARY);
            }
            return sum;
        }
    }

    private static class Employee {

        private int index;
        private String name;
        private String job;
        private int salary;

        public Employee(String name, String job, int salary) {
            this.name = name;
            this.job = job;
            this.salary = salary;
        }

        public int getIndex() {
            return index;
        }

        public void setIndex(int index) {
            this.index = index;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getJob() {
            return job;
        }

        public void setJob(String job) {
            this.job = job;
        }

        public int getSalary() {
            return salary;
        }

        public void setSalary(int age) {
            this.salary = age;
        }
    }

    private static class CurrencyFormatter extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        private NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jTable, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(jTable, value,
                isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            if (c instanceof JLabel && value instanceof Number) {
                JLabel label = (JLabel) c;
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
                Number num = (Number) value;
                String text = numberFormat.format(num);
                label.setText(text);
            }
            return c;
        }
    }
}
```