# prevent sorting of top 3 rows in jxtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swingx, jxtable

I have a JXtable. I would like to prevent the top 3 rows from being sorted. Basically the top 3 rows should always be on top and the remaining ones should be sorted according to their value.

There is a similar question on SO but i am not sure how to really apply it to my use
[Sort ROW except last row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17092951/886569)

The major difference is that i am using JXTable. Is there a easy way to do this that i am missing?

Here is my JXtable code

```
jTable1 = new JXTable();
if (isClickable) {
    jTable1.getTableHeader().setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

    //set the sorter here
} else {
    jTable1.setSortable(false);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665397/jtable-multiple-header-rows

Comment: not sure if that link applies. That one is referring to grouping of headers. Any comment on why you think its similar or any particular section of that thread i should re-read?

Comment: I thought having multi-row headers might just be like having top rows fixed on sorting. _Thanks, a next time will ellaborate more._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it took me a little while to perfect this as best I could, but here's my working example.

Basically, I made a wrapper class called `ComparableWrapper` that implements Comparable so the sorting for each column could be manipulated. For the table model, I added a `setData(Object[][] data)` method that automatically wraps all the data values in a `ComparableWrapper`. The `sorted` argument in the `ComparableWrapper` contructor determines whether the value should be sorted as normal, or stay at the top no matter what.

You'll have to manually change the class types for the columns in a few places. Anyway, here's my SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTable;

public class TableTest extends JFrame {

    public TableTest() {
        super("JXTable - first 3 rows aren't sorted");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();
        JXTable table = new JXTable();
        table.setModel(model);

        Object[][] initialData = {
            {"Zoe", new Integer(26)},
            {"Adam", new Integer(29)},
            {"Trisha", new Integer(33)},
            {"Reed", new Integer(20)},
            {"John", new Integer(3)},
            {"Kyle", new Integer(102)},
            {"Billy Bob", new Integer(27)},
            {"Sandra", new Integer(87)},
            {"Steve", new Integer(50)},
            {"Guy", new Integer(23)},
            {"Kenzie", new Integer(25)},
            {"Mary", new Integer(27)},
            {"Sally", new Integer(12)},
            {"Joe", new Integer(101)},
            {"Billy", new Integer(44)},
            {"Bob", new Integer(83)},
        };
        model.setData(initialData);

        JScrollPane tableScroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(tableScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 600);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        String[] columns = { "First Name", "Age" };
        Object[][] data = {};

        public void setData(Object[][] data) {
            for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                // Don't sort top 3 rows
                boolean sorted = i < 3 ? false : true;

                // Wrap each object so the sorting can be manipulated.
                // Change these class types as needed.
                data[i][0] = new ComparableWrapper<String>((String) data[i][0], sorted);
                data[i][1] = new ComparableWrapper<Integer>((Integer) data[i][1], sorted);
            }
            this.data = data;
            fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
            return ComparableWrapper.class;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columns.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columns[col];
        }

    }

    private class ComparableWrapper<T> implements Comparable<ComparableWrapper<T>> {

        private Comparable<T> object;
        private boolean sorted;

        public ComparableWrapper(Comparable<T> object, boolean sorted) {
            this.object = object;
            this.sorted = sorted;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(ComparableWrapper<T> o) {
            if (object instanceof Comparable<?>) {
                if (sorted && o.isSorted()) {
                    // Sort normally by default
                    return object.compareTo(o.getObject());
                } else {
                    // If an un-sorted row is being compared, don't compare at all
                    return 0;
                }
            }

            // Fallback
            return 0;
        }

        public T getObject() {
            return (T) object;
        }

        public boolean isSorted() {
            return sorted;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return object.toString();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TableTest();
    }

}
```

Comment: When i run this no data gets added to the jxtable.

Comment: @codeNinja Sorry, I forgot to add `fireTableDataChanged();` to the `setData` method on the table model. That way it'll notify the table that the data updated. I've updated my answer.

Comment: `fireTableDataChanged` populated the table. Now when i click the header with the names i get the following error: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javaapplication4.JavaApplication4$ComparableWrapper cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Comment: @codeNinja Sorry, I forgot about another small update I made - the `classes` array in the table model is not actually needed at all. Just change the `getColumnClass` method to return `ComparableWrapper.class`. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank You! Excellent answer with a working example. The bounty goes to you.