# Exclude first row filtering JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I got a problem when filtering my JTable. In fact, on my first row I have JComboBoxes in each column. And when I sort which the items of JCombo the first row is also being filtered and disappear.

Here is my Table model:

```
public static class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -768739845735375515L;
    private List<Object[]> data;
    private List<String> columnNames;

    public MyModel(List<String> columnNames, List<Object[]> data) {
        super();
        this.columnNames = columnNames;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames.get(column);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return data.get(rowIndex)[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) { // Pour modifier uniquement la cellule Statut
        if (row == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        data.get(row)[col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

    public void removeRow(int row) {
        data.remove(row);
    }
}
```

And the combo listener :

```
private void ComboListener(final JComboBox comboBox){   
    comboBox.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    try{
                    String selectedItem = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(selectedItem));
                    }catch(Exception ex){}
                }
            }            
    );
}
```

Comment: Where's your code that does the table model sorting?

Comment: Are you talking about filtering, rather than sorting? From the looks of your code, you filter based on the contents of the combo box. Then presumably the combo boxes vanish?

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16673437/1438660

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm assuming you're talking about filtering, not sorting, based on your current code.*

You could make use of the [`int.. indices` argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html#regexFilter%28java.lang.String,%20int...%29) when creating your filter:

```
int[] indices = new int[yourModel.getRowCount() -1];
for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
  indices[i] = i+1;
}

sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(selectedItem, indices));
```

This will cause your filter to apply to all the rows except row 0.